# clkhash - why is secret secret?

Tags: python

The documentation for clkhash (https://clkhash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial_api.html) states that "knowledge of this secret is sufficient to reconstruct the PII information from a CLK". My question is, how is that possible, considering that hashes are supposed to be one-way transformation? Ideally, I would like to see some code that actually does it.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the hash algorithm which are used here (MD5 and SHA-1) cannot be reverted, but if there was no secret, the CLK scheme would be highly susceptible to dictionary or brute-force attacks. That is, an attacker could simply try out potential inputs (e. g. different names and birth years), and whenever they find a matching CLK, they can be reasonably sure they've identified the person. Consumer GPUs like NVIDIA's RTX 4090 can [calculate around 160 billion(!) MD5 hashes per second](https://gist.github.com/Chick3nman/32e662a5bb63bc4f51b847bb422222fd), so it won't take long to try out a large number of possible inputs.

This is why the scheme uses keyed-hash message authentication codes (HMACs) instead of simple hashes. An HMAC can only be calculated if the key is known, so a brute-force attack is no longer feasible (unless the secret is leaked, of course).